# WPF DataGrid binding don't work caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I can't understand why it does not work..

This is my class

```
public class Article : Screen
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    public decimal Cost{ get; set; }
    public decimal Price{ get; set; }
}
```

This is XAML code of DataGrid:

```
    <DataGrid Height="211" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="12,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="521" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Code}" Header="Code" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" Header="Description" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Cost}" Header="Cost" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Price}" Header="Price" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="223,262,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"
            x:Name="AllArticles"/>
```

And this is my viewmodel

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class ArtsViewModel : Screen
{
    public List<Article> List = new List<Article>();

    public void AllArticles()
    {
        Recover recover = new Recover();  //a model called Recover
        List = recover.Import().Articles; //return a List of Article
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("List");
    }    
}
```

WHY THE DATAGRID DON'T WORK ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enable the binding conventions in *Caliburn.Micro*, you normally use the `x:Name`  property in your XAML. If you, instead of explicitly binding the `List` property to `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid`, use the name convention like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="List" Height="211" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="12,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="521" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

I believe the subsequent bindings should work as desired.

Oh, and you also need to make `List` a property instead of a field:

```
public List<Article> List { get; private set; }
```

If you want to make sure that modifications to `List` are properly reflected in your data grid, you should also make your `List` property an `IObservableCollection` with a backing field:

```
private IObservableCollection<Article> _list;
public IObservableCollection<Article> List { 
    get { return _list; }
    set {
        _list = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => List);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, as you're using CM: BindableCollection<Article>

Answer (score 1):

a) Did you set the DataContext?

b) Try "Binding="{Binding Code}" (Without Path=), works fine for me.

Comment: I tried to use without path, but don't work. I think is datacontext.
How do I set the DataContext? It 's the first time I use a datagrid, you can show me.

Answer (score 0):

For my UWP app I found that the x:Name convention didn't work and I need to use a bindable collection and bind directly to ItemsSource. I then used Path=PropertyName to specify the columns.

XAML:

```
<controls:DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  ItemsSource="{Binding RawCSVData}" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Path=Time}"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Signal" Binding="{Binding Path=Signal}"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Response" Binding="{Binding Path=Response}"/>

        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
```

CSVData.cs:

```
public class CSVData: Screen
{
    public double Time { get; set; }
    public double Signal { get; set; }
    public double Response { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel.cs snippet:

```
public BindableCollection<CSVData> RawCSVData { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
     private void _bookeditpage_ConfirmBook(Book _book, bool _isnewone) 
     {
        if (_isnewone)
        {
            Books.Add(_book);
        }
        else
        {
            //doesn't refresh datagrid
            SelectedBook = _book;
            //

            //works fine :)

            SelectedBook.BookName = _book.BookName;
            SelectedBook.IsPrenum=_book.IsPrenum;
            SelectedBook.Publisher=_book.Publisher;

           //
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question.  Perhaps a little detail would clarify